# Static Friction of the Bottom Box

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

*I feel like this looks like a homework question, but I am out of uni for a while now. Just asking this for curiosity.*

Suppose there are 2 boxes, one stack above the other. Now often I see on the internet to ask what is the static friction between the two boxes.

What I am curious about is the static friction between the floor and the lower box $B$. Is that simply the $f_{s,B}\;\leq\;\mu_{B}\left(m_A\;+\;m_B\right)\mathbf{g}$?

Comment: Hi SHY.John. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just the product of static friction coefficient and weight of the two boxes.

Comment: **Readers note:** All three answers are the same. I picked this answer since it is the simplest and gives and introduction to the other 2 answers. I highly recommend to read the other two answers to grasp a more in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am curious about is the static friction between the floor and
> the lower box $B$. Is that simply the
> $f_{s,B}\;\leq\;\mu_{B}\left(m_A\;+\;m_B\right)\mathbf{g}$?

Your equation is for the *maximum possible* static friction force between the lower box and the floor before impending sliding occurs. Up until that maximum the actual static friction force matches the net horizontal force applied to the lower block. In order to determine the actual static friction force you need information on the applied horizontal force(s) to the block(s) and do a free body diagram (FBD).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, the static friction force obeys $f_{s,B} \leq \mu_B N_B$, where $N_B$ is the magnitude of the normal force on block $B$.  This is determined by "local properties" of block $B$, namely the coefficient of friction between $B$ and the surface it rests on and the normal force exerted by this surface on $B$.  In an introductory mechanics problem, you can generally assume this is true.

Now, if there is another block $A$ sitting on top of $B$, and there are no forces with vertical components being exerted upon $A$ or $B$ other than gravity, and the system is not accelerating upwards or downwards, then it is possible to show that $N_B = (m_A + m_B) g$, and so $f_{s,B} \leq \mu_B (m_A + m_B) g$.  But this is a consequence of how the system is set up, and should not be viewed as a fundamental rule.